# Apply schengen visa multiple entry for several business trips

Tags: schengen, canada, schengen-visas, multiple-entry

I have obtained a schengen visa twice: 
1) Czech (single entry for 90 days) 
2) Germany (multiple entries for 30 days)

I have 2 business trips coming up where I will be going to a conference. I have tickets for both. One is in Paris and the other one in Greece. Paris is from May 20-24 and Greece is from June 8-13. I would like to get multiple entry visa for 90days so I don't need to apply over and over as there is a potential for another conference.

My questions are:
1) What dates should I specify in my application as I have 2 trips coming up, should it be from May 20 to June 13? or just May 20-24?

2) Which consulate should I apply? I believe Paris although how should I specify about Greece as there is nowhere in the form to do so.

Comment: Specify exactly the truth. You can attach a piece of paper to add more information. Also you will have an opportunity to explain at your interview.

Comment: What dates should I enter though? just dates of my first trip

Comment: @cHi, I don't think the Schengen short-stay visa process usually includes an interview. (The applicant must show up to have biometrics taken, but they won't get to speak to a decisionmaker at that occasion). Do you have information to the contrary?

Comment: It does include an interview where you submit the docs.

Comment: @fscore: What makes you think that is an "interview"?

Comment: As they do ask questions